# Strange error for passing parameter to forestset to draw tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, forest, arguments

I am trying to draw a simple probability tree, where the probabilites could sometimes be fraction or decimals., this means, I will have to adjust the spacing. So I tried the below code. This produces tree but label gone, and error thrown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{philex}


\forestset{
  my edge label/.style 3 args={
    edge label={node[midway, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1,xshift=#2]{#3}},
  },
}

\title{Problem customizing forest tree}
\author{parthi292929 }
\date{November 2018}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

    \scalebox{1.2}{
        \begin{forest}
        for tree={grow'=east}
          [0
            [Diseased, my edge label={above}{xshift=-2mm}{0.002}
             [Positive
             ]
             [Negative(FN)
             ]
            ]
            [No Disease
             [Positive
             ]
             [Negative
             ]        
            ]
            ]
          ]
        \end{forest}
    }


\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Might be useful if you also cite the error

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually 2 issues.

1. `style 3 args` does not exist, use `style n args={3}{...` instead.
2. You define for the 2nd argument `xshift=#2` but add one more `xshift` when you are saying `my edge label={above}{xshift=-2mm}{0.002}`.

Working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{philex}


\forestset{
  my edge label/.style n args={3}{
    edge label={node[midway, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1,xshift=#2]{#3}},
  },
}

\title{Problem customizing forest tree}
\author{parthi292929 }
\date{November 2018}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

    \scalebox{1.2}{
        \begin{forest}
        for tree={grow'=east}
          [0
            [Diseased,my edge label={above}{-2mm}{0.002}
             [Positive
             ]
             [Negative(FN)
             ]
            ]
            [No Disease
             [Positive
             ]
             [Negative
             ]        
            ]
            ]
          ]
        \end{forest}
    }


\end{document}
```

[image]

Simpler code: pgfkeys already accept comma-separated arguments, which is illustrated in `my edge label={above,xshift=-3mm}{0.002}`. And instead the `xshift` you my just use `above left` or `below left` etc., as in `my edge label={below left}{0.998}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{philex}


\forestset{
  my edge label/.style n args={2}{
    edge label={node[midway, font=\sffamily\scriptsize,#1]{#2}},
  },
}

\title{Problem customizing forest tree}
\author{parthi292929 }
\date{November 2018}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

    \scalebox{1.2}{
        \begin{forest}
        for tree={grow'=east}
          [0
            [Diseased,my edge label={above,xshift=-3mm}{0.002}
             [Positive
             ]
             [Negative(FN)
             ]
            ]
            [No Disease,my edge label={below left}{0.998}
             [Positive
             ]
             [Negative
             ]        
            ]
            ]
          ]
        \end{forest}
    }


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `above` and a negative `xshift` you may also try `above left`.

Comment: thanks marmot :) any way I could make that optional also, so I need not always give that some default value?

Comment: @PaariVendhan Yes, of course, with pgfkeys. (Sorry, I was hibernating.) What do you want to make default? (Will decouple now again for one hour.)

Comment: No, not default, just optional (so even if i do not pass anything, nothing happens foreg, what happens if i did not send xshift value - result should be if what if i did not use xshift in the style)

Comment: @PaariVendhan `node`s already allow for optional keys, so IMHO you only need 2 arguments, not three. I illustrated this in another example.